# is it possible to use 'will' to ask and give info about something that had happened in the past and something that is happening?

Tags: grammar, tense, phrase-choice

my teacher had assigned me the most confusing powerpoint ever. he told me to make a presentation on how to ask and give information about the past, present, and future but using 'will' as the sentence starter with a certain context. he told me to pay attention to these:
1. will + (simple)
2. will + (continuous)
3. will + (perfect)
how to ask and give information about the future with will is pretty obvious, but i'm confused as to how can one ask about the past and present with 'will'

Comment: You may have misunderstood your teacher. It appears that he is asking you to form questions and answers using the simple future, the future progressive, and the future perfect. That is a perfectly sensible exercise. But the progressive and perfect aspects of a verb are not the present and past tenses of that verb. Do you understand the difference between tense and aspect?

Comment: i don't think i misunderstood him. he clearly wrote it that way... i quote 'ask and give information regarding actions/events/activities that are going to happen, is currently happening, had happened/happening in the future in accordance with the context while paying attention to: will + simple, will + continuous, and will + perfect' can you please elaborate about the difference between tense and aspect? i don't really understand that. forgive me, i don't usually speak english as i am not a native speaker.

Comment: @amel You should edit the question to use that exact wording (quotation) rather than your own interpretation of it.

Comment: I have not a clue what the quoted language means. It is not even grammatical English. What may be intended is to write questions and corresponding answers in the simple future, the future progressive, and the future perfect. But the instructions as quoted have no meaning in English. I suggest you get a teacher who actually knows English.